# map function not working in ReactJs using nexttjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in ReactJS and i am using "Nextjs" framework,Right now i am using "async" function
for fetching data but unable to fetch using "map" function, in console.log ...showing me following message
" items: undefined }",Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const blog =({items}) =>{
  console.log({items});
  return(
  <div>
   </div>
);
};


//calling api for get data
export const getstaticprops=async()=>{
console.log('Om Success');
    const res=await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const posts = await res.json()
    return {
      props: { items: posts },
    }
  
}
export default blog
```

Comment: ```export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}``` try this and full example https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

Comment: @SalimBaskoy can you update my code so i can check and can implement at my side

Comment: The function _has to_ be called `getStaticProps` (not `getstaticprops`). Otherwise, Next.js will just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

test this code !

```
const blog =({posts}) =>{
  console.log(posts); \\ fix console log
  return(
  <div>

  </div>
);
};
export async function getServerSideProps(){
console.log('Om Success');
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const posts = await res.json()
    return {
      props: { posts }, \\ remove items
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine but please explain where i was wrong ? so i can learn from my mistake

Comment: @Rajni This work because the function used has the right casing, i.e. `getServerSideProps`. In your case it should be `getStaticProps` and not `getstaticprops`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props.

Comment: what version nodejs do you use ?